# Investigate correlation between one variable and combinations of others

Tags: correlation, clustering, pattern-recognition

We're conducting a study which correlate the incidence of various conditions during pregnancy and in newborns and the use of artificial reproduction technique (ART).

This way we saw that some outcomes correlated with the use of ART.

Now we would like to test another hypothesis. Instead of studying a one to one correlation (ART ~ outcome), we would like to know whether the use of ART is associated with particular associations of the outcomes.

Is it possible to investigate this?

NB: notice that in a biologically complex setting like this one it's impossible to exclude that some outcomes are indeed correlated, even with a causative link (like gestational diabetes and other morbidities during pregnancy).

Comment: Are you sure you use the term correlation properly? Correlation of a binary variable (treated/not treated with ART) with something else hardly makes sense. Correlation requires two random variables on an ordinal scale to make sense. Also, are you really interested if a random demand for ART is stochastically related to these outcomes? After all, it seems like you have simply to groups (ART, no ART) and want to compare the incidence rates of some outcomes, which in turn might influence each other.

Comment: Uhm, i'm not sure if correlation is the right term. Any way I saw other studies in which cancer cells where clustered according some genetic variables and then was seen how much these clusters corresponded to a class variable, response to treatment if I don't remember wrong.

Comment: Clustering and correlation are very different concepts. If you are unsure how to operationalize your research question for statistics, you are encouraged to explain your whole research question in your own medical terms to a statistical consultant. The consultant will find an appropriate procedure with you. I'm afraid your question is not specific enough to be answered on CV.